# Mongodb Kafka messages not seen by topic

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I encountered that my topic despite running and operating doesn't register events occuring in my MongoDB.

Everytime I insert/modify record I'm not getting anymore logs from `kafka-console-consumer` command.

Is there a way clear Kafka's cache/offset maybe?
Source and sink connection are up and running. Entire cluster is also healthy, thing is that everything worked as usual but every couple weeks I see this coming back or when I log into my Mongo cloud from other location.

`--partition 0` parameter didn't help, changing `retention_ms` to `1` too.

[image]

[image]

I checked both connectors' status and got `RUNNING`:

`curl localhost:8083/connectors | jq`
[image]

`curl localhost:8083/connectors/monit_people/status | jq`
[image]

Running `docker-compose logs connect` I found:

```
    WARN Failed to resume change stream: Resume of change stream was not possible, as the resume point may no longer be in the oplog. 286

If the resume token is no longer available then there is the potential for data loss.
Saved resume tokens are managed by Kafka and stored with the offset data.
 
When running Connect in standalone mode offsets are configured using the:
`offset.storage.file.filename` configuration.
When running Connect in distributed mode the offsets are stored in a topic.

Use the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool with the `--reset-offsets` flag to reset offsets.

Resetting the offset will allow for the connector to be resume from the latest resume token. 
Using `copy.existing=true` ensures that all data will be outputted by the connector but it will duplicate existing data.
Future releases will support a configurable `errors.tolerance` level for the source connector and make use of the `postBatchResumeToken
```

Comment: Are you missing `--from-beginning`? Otherwise, you're only going to be reading new messages. And how are you checking connector health? The up/healthy there is only verifying the connect http server is up, not any single connector is working

Comment: I didn't use `--from-beginning` at also worked in the past. I ran `curl localhost:8083/connectors | jq` with `curl localhost:8083/connectors/monit_people/status | jq` and status is `RUNNING`

Comment: Which mongo connector are you using? Are your docker images stopping at any point in this period of "every couple weeks"? If so, and you're not using volume mounts, then yes - Docker is removing the Kafka data

Comment: You could also look for errors in `docker-compose logs connect`

Comment: Connectors: `https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb` and `https://www.confluent.io/hub/snowflakeinc/snowflake-kafka-connector`. When I finish learning I simply put docker imagie down with `docker container stop $(docker container ls -a -q -f "label=io.confluent.docker")`

Comment: Okay, but stopping the container(s) will remove any existing data and any running connectors. I think you have your answer in the error there. `Saved resume tokens are managed by Kafka and stored with the offset data. Use the 'kafka-consumer-groups.sh' tool with the '--reset-offsets' flag to reset offsets.`

Comment: I ran `kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --group all-groups --reset-offsets --to-earliest --all-topics --execute` but still no luck.

Comment: Still unclear when/if you are stopping the broker and/or zookeeper container. Do all of the topics still exist?

Comment: After running `docker container stop` and re-running `docker-compose ps` I see broker, zookeeper, rest-proxy with `Exit` state.

Comment: Sure, but why are you stopping anything if you expect data to remain in the containers or the connector to pick up where it left off?

Comment: Reason for stopping is I simply don't need it to run all the time. I observerd that every restart did end with connector picking up where it left off.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - for now I simply re-established entire container from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue requires more practice with Confluent Platform thus for now I re-built entire environment by removing entire container with:

`docker system prune -a -f --volumes`

`docker container stop $(docker container ls -a -q -f "label=io.confluent.docker")`.

After running `docker-compose up -d` all is up and working.